# Which version of Zend FrameWork Should I learn 1.11.3 OR 1.8?

Tags: zend-framework

I want to learn the `Zend Framework(ZFW)`. The latest version of ZFW is `1.11.3` . The problem is that I have some books(`Zend Framework in Action , Zend Framework Techniques Build a Full CMS.Project ,Zend Framework 1.8 Web Application Development`) which are written for the version `1.8`. Should I download the version `1.8` and start reading that book. If so, can I write project in the latest version of ZFW after learning `1.8`? If not can anybody please suggest some book for `1.11.3`. I do have a good knowledge in OOP,php/mySQL,Javascript etc.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you the official documentation: http://framework.zend.com. And in my opinion, you should learn always about the last stable release.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please recommend some book also?